Replacing a Variable with its Expected Value
This is a follow-up question to my previous questions (Difficulty understanding matrix notation,  Help expanding matrix equations)
Originally I start with this system of equations:

Z only depends on previous values of Z
X and Y depend on previous values of X and Y, as well as previous values of Z
X and Y also depend on the current forecasted value of Z

$$Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
$$X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3 Z_{t}  + \epsilon_{1t}$$
$$Y_t = \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} 
 + \gamma_4 Z_{t} + \epsilon_{2t}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -\gamma_3 \\
0 & 1 & -\gamma_4 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
Y_t \\
Z_t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} \\
\alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} \\
\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{pmatrix}$$
This created a endogeneity problem, so I then performed the following transformation based on replacing $Z_t$ with its expexted value at $Z_{t-1}$:
$$
E_{t-1}[Z_t] = E_{t-1}[\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t] = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
Z_t &= \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
X_t &= \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3 E_{t-1}[Z_t] + \epsilon_{1t} \\
Y_t &= \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4 E_{t-1}[Z_t] + \epsilon_{2t}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
X_t &= \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3 (\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}) + \epsilon_{1t} \\
Y_t &= \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4 (\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}) + \epsilon_{2t}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
X_t &= \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} \\
Y_t &= \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_2 + \gamma_4\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} \\
Z_t &= \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
Y_t \\
Z_t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_1 & \gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi \\
\alpha_2 & \beta_2 & \gamma_2 + \gamma_4\phi \\
0 & 0 & \phi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_{t-1} \\
Y_{t-1} \\
Z_{t-1}
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_3\theta & 1 & 0 \\
\gamma_4\theta & 0 & 1 \\
\theta & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_{t-1} \\
\epsilon_{1t} \\
\epsilon_{2t}
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\epsilon_t
$$
$$ Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$
$$ X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} $$
$$ Y_t = \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_2 + \gamma_4\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} $$
I have this question: Is the distribution of $Z_t$ different from $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$?
I tried to investigate this myself:

Part 1: Distribution of $E_{t-1}[Z_t] $

$$
Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$
The expectation $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$ is based on the information available up to time $t-1$. Since $ \epsilon_t $ is independent of its previous values, the conditional expectation $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$ is:
$$
E_{t-1}[Z_t] = E_{t-1}[\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t] = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}
$$
Since both $ Z_{t-1} $ and $ \epsilon_{t-1} $ are known at time $ t-1 $, $ E_{t-1}[Z_t] $ is a deterministic quantity given by:
$$
E_{t-1}[Z_t] = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}
$$
$ Z_{t-1} $ and $ \epsilon_{t-1} $ are random variables with known distributions at time $ t-1 $.
Assume:

$ Z_{t-1} $ is normally distributed with $ Z_{t-1} \sim N(\mu_{Z_{t-1}}, \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2) $
$ \epsilon_{t-1} $ is normally distributed with $ \epsilon_{t-1} \sim N(0, \sigma_\epsilon^2) $

Since $ E_{t-1}[Z_t] $ is a linear combination of $ Z_{t-1} $ and $ \epsilon_{t-1} $, $ E_{t-1}[Z_t] $ will also be normally distributed:
$$
E_{t-1}[Z_t] \sim N(\phi \mu_{Z_{t-1}}, \phi^2 \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2 + \theta^2 \sigma_\epsilon^2)
$$
Thus, the probability distribution for $ E_{t-1}[Z_t] $ is:
$$
E_{t-1}[Z_t] \sim N\left(\phi \mu_{Z_{t-1}}, \phi^2 \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2 + \theta^2 \sigma_\epsilon^2 \right)
$$

Part 2: Distribution of $ Z_t $

$$
Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$
Assume :

$ Z_{t-1} $ is normally distributed: $ Z_{t-1} \sim N(\mu_{Z_{t-1}}, \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2) $
$ \epsilon_{t-1} $ and $ \epsilon_t $ are independent and normally distributed: $ \epsilon_{t-1} \sim N(0, \sigma_\epsilon^2) $ and $ \epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma_\epsilon^2) $

Since $ Z_t $ is a linear combination of normally distributed variables, it is also normally distributed. The expectation and variance of $ Z_t $ are as follows:
Expectation of $ Z_t $:
$$
E[Z_t] = E[\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t] = \phi E[Z_{t-1}] + \theta E[\epsilon_{t-1}] + E[\epsilon_t]
$$
Given $ E[\epsilon_{t-1}] = E[\epsilon_t] = 0 $, we have:
$$
E[Z_t] = \phi \mu_{Z_{t-1}}
$$
Variance of $ Z_t $:
$$
\text{Var}(Z_t) = \text{Var}(\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t)
$$
Since $ Z_{t-1} $, $ \epsilon_{t-1} $, and $ \epsilon_t $ are independent:
$$
\text{Var}(Z_t) = \phi^2 \text{Var}(Z_{t-1}) + \theta^2 \text{Var}(\epsilon_{t-1}) + \text{Var}(\epsilon_t)
$$
Substituting the variances:
$$
\text{Var}(Z_t) = \phi^2 \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2 + \theta^2 \sigma_\epsilon^2 + \sigma_\epsilon^2
$$
Thus, the variance is:
$$
\text{Var}(Z_t) = \phi^2 \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2 + (\theta^2 + 1)\sigma_\epsilon^2
$$
Thus, the probability distribution of $ Z_t $ is:
$$
Z_t \sim N\left(\phi \mu_{Z_{t-1}}, \phi^2 \sigma_{Z_{t-1}}^2 + (\theta^2 + 1)\sigma_\epsilon^2\right)
$$
Conclusion: I have spent the last few days working on this and its all "alphabet soup" in my head right now. Can someone please give me some pointers on if my understanding is logical?
